# opcua-asyncio : Subscriptions to multiples addresses

Tags: python, python-asyncio, opc-ua

I'm making monitoring client using opcua-asyncio. The goal is to keep track of the values of a list of nodes for a list of machines. But there's no examples on how to manages multiples connections in the documentation and I'm a bit lost.

The subscription works fine for one machine :

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "..")
import time
import asyncio
from asyncua import Client, ua, Node

url = 'opc.tcp://192.168.200.204:8999'

class SubscriptionHandler:
    def datachange_notification(self, node: Node, val, data):
        print(str(val))
        
async def main():
    client = Client(url=url)
    async with client:
        handler = SubscriptionHandler()
        subscription = await client.create_subscription(500, handler)
        nodes = [
            client.get_node("ns=2;s=CncData/MachineStatus/Status"),
            client.get_node("ns=2;s=CncData/MachineStatus/Part/PieceToDo"),
        ]
        await subscription.subscribe_data_change(nodes)
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

The result is the subscriptions being created, then the two values returned, so everything's good.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nUNR.png)

The thing is, I can't simply add a loop that will iterate a list of adresses at the start of the main, because the subscriptions is pooled with a "while True". This is what I tried :

```
ENDPOINT = [list_of_addresses]

class SubscriptionHandler:
    def datachange_notification(self, node: Node, val, data):
        print(str(val))

clients = []
handles = []
async def main():
    try:
        for add in ENDPOINT:
            cli = Client(url=add)
            clients.append(cli)
        for client in clients:
            async with client:
                var = client.get_node("ns=2;s=CncData/MachineStatus/Status")
                handler = SubscriptionHandler()
                # We create a Client Subscription.
                subscription = await client.create_subscription(500, handler)
                nodes = [
                    var,
                    client.get_node("ns=2;s=CncData/MachineStatus/Part/PieceToDo"),
                ]
                # We subscribe to data changes for two nodes (variables).
                handles.append(await subscription.subscribe_data_change(nodes))
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(1000)
    except (ConnectionError, ua.UaError):
        print("CONNEXION ERROR")
        await asyncio.sleep(2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

The subscriptions are indeed created, but the subscription's handlers are never called :

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o50cS.png)

I don't understand where to put the "while true" that is essential for pooling.

Comment: create a new `async` function and call this function from the `async main()`...  it will be cleaner for you (especially because the async notation in python is verbose).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a function for the connection. And make a asyncio task for each client.

```
async def connection_loop(add):
    try:
        client = Client(url=add)
        async with client:
            var = client.get_node("ns=2;s=CncData/MachineStatus/Status")
            handler = SubscriptionHandler()
            # We create a Client Subscription.
            subscription = await client.create_subscription(500, handler)
            nodes = [
                var,
                client.get_node("ns=2;s=CncData/MachineStatus/Part/PieceToDo"),
            ]
            # We subscribe to data changes for two nodes (variables).
            handles.append(await subscription.subscribe_data_change(nodes))
            while 1:
                await asyncio.sleep(2)
                await client.check_connection()  # Throws a exception if connection is lost
    except (ConnectionError, ua.UaError):
        print("CONNEXION ERROR")
        await asyncio.sleep(2)

async def main():
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(connection_loop(add)) for add in ENDPOINT]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It does make sense to make a function and a task per client. This however does not changes the script's behaviour : There's still no pooling. The subscriptions needs to be kept alive and the "while true" seems like the privilegied way when looking at the examples from the documentation. And this is my actual problem.

Comment: My bad, update the code so that the connection is alive and the function will only return if the connection is lost.